# Slow java builds, I like to make small incremental changes and view the page in the browser

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I have a MBP i7 processor.

I like to make small changes in my code and view it in the browser, but I find building my spring mvc app (using intelliJ) and pushing it to Tomcat takes a long time.

Is there something that I can

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [JRebel](http://www.zeroturnaround.com/jrebel/). It provides hot code swapping and integrates with a lot of the major frameworks to provide configuration reloading, too. It's very simple to set up and use. They offer a 1-month trial, and you can get an additional 3 months via a [special summer program](http://www.zeroturnaround.com/jrebel/giveaways/?campaign=sanantoniojug).

Comment: @codecompleting: Yes, you do, but at this point, it's a pretty unique solution. I don't know of any competing products.